# Filesize 0 mysqldump

Tags: php

I am using Windows 7 and using php i am backing up my database with the help of mysqldump. The file gets successfully written but the size remains always 0. Any idea why is this happening?

Note :- If i type the same command in command line, it works. This is my function :-

```
   public static function BackupDatabase($backupPath){
        $fileName = uniqid() .'.sql';
        $backupCommand = 'mysqldump -u ' . DBUsername .' -p' . DBPassword .' abc >' . $backupPath . $fileName  ;

        $retVal = '';
        $feedback = system($backupCommand, $retVal);
        if($feedback == NULL || $feedback == '')
            return 'Database backed up successfully by name ' . $fileName;
        else
            return $feedback;
    }
```

**EDIT :-**

```
public static function BackupDatabase($backupPath){
        $fileName = uniqid() .'.sql';
        $backupCommand = 'mysqldump -u ' . DBUsername . ' abc > ' . $backupPath . $fileName .' 2>&1'  ;
        echo $backupCommand;
        $retVal = '';
        $feedback = system($backupCommand, $retVal);
        echo $retVal;
        if($feedback == NULL || $feedback == '')
            return 'Database backed up successfully by name ' . $fileName;
        else
            return $feedback;
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're not checking `retVal`. What does it contain?

Comment: Does `[...]system('C:\path\to\mysqldump'.$backupCommand, $retVal);[...]` work? (need to rework the `$backupCommand` to remove mysqldump from the string)

Comment: @Ankit then you're getting an error. Try adding ` 2>&1` to the command line string to get errors

Comment: @Pekka :- please see my edited post. I am not getting any error even after adding 2>&1

Comment: @DrColossos  and @Pekka :- please read my comment to ajreal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe is caused by the environment setting.
You can execute mysqldump successfully in the command line as you probably has mysqldump register in your environment.

While running in a PHP, the path to mysqldump might not recognized by user that running the web server.

And

```
$feedback = system('unknown program > file', $retval);
```

Will always set `$feeback = '';` even PHP cannot find where is your mysqldump program, it still pipe a single character to backup file.

You can put in absolute path to mysqldump to test again.

Comment: Hi ajreal, you are close to my answer. I get `'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` so i tried to put absolute path which is 'C:\\Program Files\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.1.36\\bin\\mysqldump -u` now i get error `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` Does that help?

Comment: @Ankit Rathod : it seems you have to escape space in the absolute path, like `C:\Program\ Files...` - Or try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Comment: if i escape i still get this error : `'C:\Program\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: @Ankit Rathod - I have a dirty workaround, where you can just place the mysqldump program into C drive, like `C:\mysqldump` ...

Comment: @ajreal :- Great patch work! It started working :). Now i should sleep it's 1:15 in morning here. If possible please suggest how can we do without this patch work later. Thanks anyways. Vote and tick mark for you!

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check your `$backupCommand` string. It seems to me that there are some spaces missing (e.g. in the vicinity of `'-p'`).

Comment: - The same command works on command line on Windows 7 atleast. If i remove -p (since there is no password currently) then also it doesn't work. All i get after executing the function is a empty file.

Answer (score 0):

After much headache, this syntax worked for me:

cmd /c " C:\mysqldump.exe -h $mysql_server -u $mysql_user --password=$mysql_password $dbname > C:\Dump.sql "